# How to use ReplicationDriver with multiple EntityManager with Spring

Tags: mysql, spring, read-replication

I have 2 databases (let's call them `User` and `Stuff`), connected to a single Spring-java-web-application via 2 different `EntityManager`. `Stuff` has read-replica associated with it.

When I'm using `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to connect to both the dbs, it's working fine and the app is able to connect with both the dbs. But when I'm using `com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver` to connect to `Stuff` (to use read-replica) and `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to connect to `User`, the app is not able to connect to `User` and it gives:

`Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!`

Can anyone suggest, how to use 2 `EntityManager` with read-replica?